# On Posting link information in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

When we post link , its information automatically fetched .
How this can be achieved in codeigniter php API? Is there any API for this . Please help me out.

For example as we do in facebook, whatever we share its basic information comes along.

Comment: you have to use headers in the meta tags as it is in the facebook https://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Comment: Use PHP CUrl library